# Can human perception differentiate between monochromatic and polychromatic light?

Tags: human-biology, human-eye, perception, light

Maybe monochromatic is not the right word, what I mean is light consisting of a single wavelength (i.e. a spectral color) versus light composed of photons of multiple wavelengths (intermediate color).

For example, suppose we had a single, [violet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_(color)) "laser" and a set of "lasers" combining into a [purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple) color.*

Is it possible to combine the latter light sources such that their composite would perfectly match the violet one such that both look the same to a human eye (assuming perfect alignment)?

And would they look the same to all human eyes?

My guess is a no, because people might have different susceptibility to red and blue hues, and their aggregation functions may differ as well.

* Apparently, there are alternative definitions to distinguish the two colors (purple is reddish, violet bluish), but I am referring to the ones found in Wikipedia: Purple being an intermediate color and violet being a pure spectral color.

Interesting article on color perception in the animal kingdom:
https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/06/experiments-show-hummingbirds-see-colors-youve-never-dreamed-of/

Comment: The short answer is no. Because of metamerism, the human vision system cannot distinguish monochromatic light from the infinitely many metameric equivalents that elicit an identical tristimulus response as that of the monochromic light.

Comment: There might be nonlinearities in the photoreceptor, and chromatic aberrations of the lens (optics) that might allow a well trained eye to discriminate using tricks...(just a guess, hence not an answer)

Comment: Err... You're presumably reading this on a computer display, no?  Which produces colors by combining essentially monochromatic red, green, and blue pixels.  So can you see differences?

Comment: @jamesqf well, people can perceive flickering on computer displays, even on LCDs with temporal dithering, as I do, and there may be reasons why people distinguish between purple and violet, even leading to different names for the "same" perceived color. And if you look closely at an RGB display, you can see red, green and blue dots. Also, some people are tetrachromats and can see differences in skin tones where trichromats cannot. Some can even see polarization. Certain purple and violet hues might look the same to some people but different to other people, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @jamesqf also, I don't have proper, comparable monochrome light sources to compare them in any scientifically significant manner, much less people to experiment on.

Comment: @Archimedix:  Those red, blue, and green dots are monochromatic, or nearly so, yet combining them produces a multitude of perceived colors.  What I'm suggesting is that you experiment on yourself, and see whether those computer-generated colors look different than "natural" ones.  As for the flicker that some people can see (I'm one, at least on older displays), that's a function of scan lines & refresh rates, nothing to do with color.

Comment: @jamesqf I have no polychromatic light sources I could compare to those RGB dots, and I have no monochromatic light that is comparable to a mic of those RGB dots. Regarding flicker, temporal dithering uses different colors one after another to create an "average" color, so yes, in theory, most people should have similar perception (maybe along a Gaussian distribution). However, a prism would be able to make a monochromatic ray of light distinguishable from a ray of polychromatic light, and lenses do have prismatic effects.

Comment: @Archimedix: Why not create an image that is say all red - RGB = (255,0,0)?  That should be a pretty good approximation to a monochromatic source, no?  (You could test it with a prism.)  Then compare it to something that is naturally red,

Comment: @jamesqf say I compare a red patch on the screen with a piece of red paper of the same size: Both look different to me, of course, but this is because of their different surfaces/textures/hues/brightness/reflection/viewing angle and one consists of pixels where maybe one third is black while the paper is all red. Using a red LED will yield different properties, but the verdict is the same. Too many factors. Does something that looks the same to me look the same to everyone else? Is it because my two test objects are not equal enough, or do different eyes/brains render them differently?